# Array 2 string conversion while using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, arrays, curl, libcurl, notice

I have following code:

```
// $postfields = array();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
```

My `$postfields` variable is an array of parameters. And i have a notice there is array to string conversion. It works tho.

I could use `http_build_query()` function to nullify notice, however i use `@path_to_file` to include post files. and `http_build_query()` breaks file includes.

I'm wondering if there is more "proper" way to do this. Without generating a notice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are some values of `$postfields` arrays themselves? This is most likely what's causing the notice. `curl_setops` expects its third parameter to be an array whose keys and values are strings, as is stated in [PHP's manual page for the function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), though it might not be very clear:

> This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value.

In this quote, the key point is that para1/2 and val1/2 are strings, and if you want, you can provide them as an array where keys are para1 and para2, and values are val1 and val2.

There are **two ways to eliminate the notices**.

The **first** is to use `http_build_query()` and replace your uses of `@filepath` by [CURLFile objects](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php). This is only possible if you're using PHP 5.5 or above, unfortunately. The manual's page has a pretty clear and simple [example of use](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php#117920).

If using CURLFiles is not an option for you, then the **second** way is to `json_encode()` the values of your `$postfields` array which are arrays themselves. This isn't elegant, and it requires you to decode the JSON on the other side.

Comment: Indeed, 3 values of this array are arrays themselves... I don't use them so those are probably not exported properly.
Didn't think those could be inner arrays.

Comment: using `http_build_query` with `CURLFiles` doesn't work. The `CURLFiles` will get converted into arrays and just come across as regular `$_POST` data.

Answer (score 10):

j11e's answer won't work if you want to send multidimensional arrays

Try this recursive function.

https://gist.github.com/yisraeldov/ec29d520062575c204be7ab71d3ecd2f

```
<?php
function build_post_fields( $data,$existingKeys='',&$returnArray=[]){
    if(($data instanceof CURLFile) or !(is_array($data) or is_object($data))){
        $returnArray[$existingKeys]=$data;
        return $returnArray;
    }
    else{
        foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
            build_post_fields($item,$existingKeys?$existingKeys."[$key]":$key,$returnArray);
        }
        return $returnArray;
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, build_post_fields($postfields));
```

Comment: That is what I needed. In order to use <input name="field[]" value="1">  <input name="field[]" value="2"> etc. in curl request this is the right answer. Thanks Yysrael

Answer (score 4):

Using Laravel one thing that worked for me was to use the tag 'Content-Type: application/json' in the request header, and sending my data json encoded like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
```

In the function that receives the parameters in the request I had no need to use the json decode function, I access to the parameters just like

`$request->something`

Answer (score 0):

After research for an hour, here the way i fixed my code:

```
$strVar = '';
if ($data) {
        $ea = build_post_fields($data);
        foreach($ea as $key=>$val) {
                $strVar.= "$key=$val&";
        }
}


/* eCurl */
$curl = curl_init($url);

/* Set Array data to POST */
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($strVar) );
```

And here is the function I take from @Yisrael Dov below:

```
function build_post_fields( $data, $existingKeys='', $returnArray=[]){
    if(($data instanceof CURLFile) or !(is_array($data) or is_object($data))){
        $returnArray[$existingKeys]=$data;
        return $returnArray;
    }
    else{
        foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
            build_post_fields($item,$existingKeys?$existingKeys."[$key]":$key,$returnArray);
        }
        return $returnArray;
    }
}
```

That work perfectly! You can post a deep array like:

```
$post_var = array(
'people' => array('Lam', 'Hien', 'Nhi'),
'age' => array(12, 22, 25)
);
```

Good day!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for your answer, but you should credit Yisrael Dov for coming with the function build_post_fields in [his own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41144063/5820258), posted previously. And beware, your function build a query string with an unnecessary trailing `&`.

Comment: Thank you for your note, i am sorry, `build_post_fields` is belong to @yisrael-dov