# How to properly upload files over pangea API using curl in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to upload file to pangea server using curl in PHP.  Here is the required parameters

```
curl -sSLX POST 'https://file-scan.aws.us.pangea.cloud/v1/scan' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <your_token>' \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
-F 'request={"provider":"crowdstrike"};type=application/json' \
-F 'upload=@test.png;type=application/octet-stream'
```

My issue is how to pass **F** parameters in the param request as per below

```
-F 'request={"provider":"crowdstrike"};type=application/json' \
-F 'upload=@test.png;type=application/octet-stream'
```

Here is my coding so far:

```
 <?php

$myfile ='data_file.png';
    $accesstoken ='access token goes here';
    $data_param= '{}';
    $url ='https://file-scan.aws.us.pangea.cloud/v1/scan';
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data', "Authorization: Bearer $accesstoken"));  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_param);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
     echo $output = curl_exec($ch); 
    
    
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    
    // catch error message before closing
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        //echo $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    }
    
    curl_close($ch);  
    
    ?>
```

Comment: `-F` just means a "standard" form parameter. Your `$data_param` should be an array, containing two entries `request` and `upload`. For the `upload` value, use https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php And remove the `Content-Type` header, cURL will set that itself (and include the necessary boundary.)

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for commenting. please can you provide little code sample of that

Comment: I have tried this but not working . `$cfile = curl_file_create('test.png');
           $data_param = array('upload' => $cfile,'request' => '{"provider":"crowdstrike"}'
           );`

Comment: User comments in the manual for curl_setopt say, _"CURLOPT_POST must be left unset if you want the Content-Type header set to "multipart/form-data" (e.g., when CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is an array)."_, so try and remove that. If the API also insists on the content-type for the `request` parameter explicitly to be set as `application/json` _inside_ the multipart request, then you'd have to go research how to do that, I don't know off the top of my head if that is directly possible using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

Comment: Maybe that can be achieved using the `CURLStringFile` class - which I am now seeing I already suggested here once, https://stackoverflow.com/q/75861453/1427878, but the person asking there solved it by switching from PHP cURL to guzzle in the end.